# How to use websockets (socket.io) with spdy http2

Tags: node.js, socket.io, http2, spdy

Is there a workaround to use WebSockets with spdy or HTTP/2

I want to avoid re-writing the client code if possible. 
But this blog post suggests WebSockets are not supported in HTTP/2.

> https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/06/15/no-websockets-over-http2/
>   There’s was once a draft submitted that describes how websockets over
>   HTTP/2 could’ve been done. It didn’t get any particular interest in
>   the IETF HTTP working group back then and as far as I’ve seen, there
>   has been very little general interest in any group to pick up this
>   dropped ball and continue running. It just didn’t go any further.

The websockets are adding 20-30 seconds to the latency. To remove this latency, 
what options do I have? I can re-write the client and the server to use http2 style server push, do I have other options?

The code uses Express via zappajs

Comment: 20-30 seconds does not make sense.  You should be able to connect a webSocket in a few hundred ms and send packets either way in a tens of ms.  Something else is busted in your configuration that you won't need HTTP/2 to fix.  You should fix your configuration first before you talk about rewriting protocols.  For example, I have a raspberry Pi running node.js and I can make a webSocket connection to it in 50ms.

Comment: http://sheet.cellmaster.com.au/carbonoffset/app  There are about 30 requests in total. Some of them require data from the backend database, but 90% of it looks like network lag, as when I run on a local machine it loads on about 2 seconds.

Comment: I don't know what to look at in that page.  Your web socket connections are being established in 250ms.  If you're making 30 requests to load a page, that's a major design problem.  You should be able to load your page in just a few requests.  Add functionality to your server to get all the data you need for a page in on more than a few requests.

Comment: It also looks like you are sending large amounts of data over the webSocket (like 500k) more than once.  This looks to me like you just have a really inefficient design, not a protocol problem.

Comment: I'd suggest you learn how to use the network tab in the Chrome debugger.  It will show you all the requests your page is making, how much data they are sending and how long each one takes.  For webSocket connections, you have to look inside them to see the individual messages, but the Chrome debugger supports that too.  I see 36 network requests plus a number of webSocket requests just to load the page.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am using the network tab in Chrome. The code is here https://github.com/audreyt/ethercalc FYI because of the cache, many smaller requests is the favoured method with http2  - The 500k of data looks bad, I had not noticed.

Comment: I promise you there's no circumstance where 40 network requests downloading more than a megabyte of data to load a page is a speedy design - even worse on a network with a bit of latency (like mobile).  Do you really not see how you've caused your own performance issue?

Comment: @jfriend00 the code is not my design

Comment: Well fix the design if you want faster loading.  I'm just observing what you've got and what is making it a lot slower than it could be.